# Joining a branch drain line at a 30 degree angle?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

In order to bring a sink drain line over to the main drain line, I really need to join it in at a 30 degree angle. 45 degrees puts the wye outside the building. Searching on google for a 30 degree wye produced no results, so I'm guessing this either doesn't exist? What do plumbers normally do in cases there they need a 30 degree wye in the waste line?

I could go 90 degree from the fixture, 45 degree bend, then 45 degree wye, but I'd rather keep the line as direct as possible without the extra direction change in there if possible.

Answer (score 1):

How do plumbers get a 30 degree angle from PVC ?

There are lots of ways to go about it for example reworking your plumbing, but the easier way is to just buy the 30 Degree PVC pipe that you need.

Below is not an endorsement but a reference for where you can get it .. of course a plumbing supply might have them in stock and on hand for same day pickup ..

https://www.supplyhouse.com/PVC-Schedule-40-30-deg-Elbows-15206000

Answer (score 0):

15 degree elbows are commonly available. Seems that would get you there with a 45 degree wye.

You can achieve any angle you need by using a combination of elbows. Two 90s, with one pointing downward, effectively create a swivel of infinite angle adjustment.

If you don't have the height available for that, use a combination of lesser-angle elbows with a downward component. A little experimenting nearly always gets you the result you need.